# Repeat rows of a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, repeat

I want to repeat the rows of a data.frame, each `N` times. The result should be a new `data.frame` (with `nrow(new.df) == nrow(old.df) * N`) keeping the data types of the columns.

Example for N = 2:

```
                        A B   C
  A B   C             1 j i 100
1 j i 100     -->     2 j i 100
2 K P 101             3 K P 101
                      4 K P 101
```

So, each row is repeated 2 times and characters remain characters, factors remain factors, numerics remain numerics, ...

My first attempt used apply: `apply(old.df, 2, function(co) rep(co, each = N))`, but this one transforms my values to characters and I get:

```
     A   B   C    
[1,] "j" "i" "100"
[2,] "j" "i" "100"
[3,] "K" "P" "101"
[4,] "K" "P" "101"
```

Answer (score 173, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = letters[1:2]) 
df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), each = 2), ]
```

Comment: You can use `n.times <- c(2,4) ; df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), n.times),]` if you want to vary the number of times each line is repeated.

Answer (score 98):

A clean `dplyr` solution, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237350/repeating-rows-of-data-frame-in-dplyr#comment63896747_38237805)

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(x = 1:2, y = c("a", "b"))
df %>% slice(rep(1:n(), each = 2))
```

Comment: This is the preferable solution imo because it works cleanly in a pipe.

Answer (score 35):

There is a lovely vectorized solution that repeats only certain rows n-times each, possible for example by adding an `ntimes` column to your data frame:

```
  A B   C ntimes
1 j i 100      2
2 K P 101      4
3 Z Z 102      1
```

Method:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c("j","K","Z"), B=c("i","P","Z"), C=c(100,101,102), ntimes=c(2,4,1))
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, rep, df$ntimes))
```

Result:

```
  A B   C ntimes
1 Z Z 102      1
2 j i 100      2
3 j i 100      2
4 K P 101      4
5 K P 101      4
6 K P 101      4
7 K P 101      4
```

This is very similar to Josh O'Brien and Mark Miller's method:

```
df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$ntimes),]
```

However, that method appears quite a bit slower:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c("j","K","Z"), B=c("i","P","Z"), C=c(100,101,102), ntimes=c(2000,3000,4000))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$ntimes),],
  as.data.frame(lapply(df, rep, df$ntimes)),
  times = 10
)
```

Result:

```
Unit: microseconds
                                      expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
   df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$ntimes), ] 3563.113 3586.873 3683.7790 3613.702 3657.063 4326.757    10
 as.data.frame(lapply(df, rep, df$ntimes))  625.552  654.638  676.4067  668.094  681.929  799.893    10
```

Comment: I think that this is the most versatile solution, as it allows you to assign different number of replications per line! I am curious, is there a way to do this in tidyverse?

Comment: @TCS see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75962253/2934203

Answer (score 12):

If you can repeat the whole thing, or subset it first then repeat that, then [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275260/how-can-i-repeat-a-data-frame/13316594#13316594) may be helpful. Once again:

```
library(mefa)
rep(mtcars,10)
```

or simply

```
mefa:::rep.data.frame(mtcars)
```

Comment: Aha! Another brilliant R function hidden deep inside an obcure specialist  package with a totally unrelated name. I love this language!

Answer (score 9):

Adding to what @dardisco mentioned about `mefa::rep.data.frame()`, it's very flexible.

You can either **repeat each row N times**:

```
rep(df, each=N)
```

or **repeat the entire dataframe N times** (think: like when you recycle a vectorized argument)

```
rep(df, times=N)
```

Two thumbs up for `mefa`! I had never heard of it until now and I had to write manual code to do this.

Answer (score 7):

For reference and adding to answers citing mefa, it might worth to take a look on the implementation of `mefa::rep.data.frame()` in case you don't want to include the whole package:

```
> data <- data.frame(a=letters[1:3], b=letters[4:6])
> data
  a b
1 a d
2 b e
3 c f
> as.data.frame(lapply(data, rep, 2))
  a b
1 a d
2 b e
3 c f
4 a d
5 b e
6 c f
```

Answer (score 5):

The rep.row function seems to sometimes make lists for columns, which leads to bad memory hijinks.  I have written the following which seems to work well:

```
library(plyr)
rep.row <- function(r, n){
  colwise(function(x) rep(x, n))(r)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution similar as `mefa:::rep.data.frame`, but a little faster and cares about row names:

```
rep.data.frame <- function(x, times) {
    rnames <- attr(x, "row.names")
    x <- lapply(x, rep.int, times = times)
    class(x) <- "data.frame"
    if (!is.numeric(rnames))
        attr(x, "row.names") <- make.unique(rep.int(rnames, times))
    else
        attr(x, "row.names") <- .set_row_names(length(rnames) * times)
    x
}
```

Compare solutions:

```
library(Lahman)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
    mefa:::rep.data.frame(Batting, 10),
    rep.data.frame(Batting, 10),
    Batting[rep.int(seq_len(nrow(Batting)), 10), ],
    times = 10
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                                            expr       min       lq     mean   median        uq       max neval cld
#>              mefa:::rep.data.frame(Batting, 10) 127.77786 135.3480 198.0240 148.1749  278.1066  356.3210    10  a 
#>                     rep.data.frame(Batting, 10)  79.70335  82.8165 134.0974  87.2587  191.1713  307.4567    10  a 
#>  Batting[rep.int(seq_len(nrow(Batting)), 10), ] 895.73750 922.7059 981.8891 956.3463 1018.2411 1127.3927    10   b
```

Answer (score 1):

try using for example

```
N=2
rep(1:4, each = N)
```

as an index

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would to first get row indices, append extra copies of the df, and then order by the indices:

```
df$index = 1:nrow(df)
df = rbind(df,df)
df = df[order(df$index),][,-ncol(df)]
```

Although the other solutions may be shorter, this method may be more advantageous in certain situations.