# How can I repeat a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

It's easy to repeat a data.frame once,

```
mt2 <- rbind(mtcars, mtcars)
```

But what's an R-like way to do this generally? If I want 10 copies of `mtcars` together I could

```
mt10 <- mtcars
for (i in 2:10) mt10 <- rbind(mt10, mtcars)
```

which is plenty concise, but seems not in the spirit of R. Is there a better way to do this, or a clever trick using vector recycling?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a very simple method:

```
mtcars[rep(1:nrow(mtcars),2),]
```

or using better "grammar":

```
mtcars[rep(seq_len(nrow(mtcars)),2),]
```

As GSee notes below, one difference here is that `rbind` will replicate the row names exactly, while using indexing will force unique row names by appending digits. Off the top of my head, I think the only fix would be to set the row names (again using `rep`) after the fact.

Comment: Although that gives different rownames, so `identical(rbind(mtcars, mtcars), mtcars[rep(1:nrow(mtcars),2),])` is FALSE

Comment: I was disappointed that `rep(mtcars, 10)` didn't work, but of course this is the way to go about it with `rep`.

Answer (score 6):

@joran's answer is very elegant and you should use it if duplicating the rownames isn't required. However, this way will also duplicate the rownames:

`do.call(rbind, replicate(10, mtcars[1:10, ], simplify=FALSE))`

Answer (score 3):

If you can tolerate another package:

```
require(mefa)
rep(mtcars,10)
```

- works after all!

It appears a little faster:

```
system.time(mtcars[rep(1:nrow(mtcars),1e5),])
system.time(mtcars[rep(seq_len(nrow(mtcars)),1e5),])
system.time(rep(mtcars,1e5))
```

Gives:

```
 user  system elapsed 
 17.41    0.19   17.89
 17.11    0.31   17.91
 6.79    0.70    7.67
```

Caveats: 1) rep will not reproduce the row names; this is a separate step. 2) `mefa::rep(mtcars,10)` doesn't work as: `Error: 'rep' is not an exported object from 'namespace:mefa'`. Also `mefa:::rep(mtcars,10)` gives `object 'rep' not found`. Not sure why this is...

Comment: Because what `mefa` provides is a `rep` method for data.frames, so `mefa:::rep.data.frame(mtcars, 10)` works.

Comment: Also, looking at `mefa:::rep.data.frame`, it's a one-liner so no need to load the package. `rep.data.frame <- function(x, ...) as.data.frame(lapply(x, rep, ...))`

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr`-based solution (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47780537/5727278))

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% slice(rep(1:n(), 2))  # 2 copies of data frame
```