# repeat dataframe n times whilst adding column

Tags: r

This is my reproducible code:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2), y = c(3, 4))

df1 <- df %>% mutate(z = 1)
df2 <- df %>% mutate(z = 2)
df3 <- df %>% mutate(z = 3)

df <- rbind(df1, df2, df3)

df
```

I repeat the original data frame df 3 times, whilst adding one column where the number in the column indicated the repetition. In my use case, I have to do this more than 3 times. I could use a loop but is there a neater way? I guess i cannot use expand.grid.

Comment: `cbind(df, z = rep(1:n, each = nrow(df)))` where `n` is how many repeats you want.

Comment: @qdread This will not work in general, because `cbind` converts to matrix, instead of data.frame

Comment: @CoreyLevinson I think `cbind` has a `data.frame` method so it should work.

Comment: @CoreyLevinson as long as you start with a data frame, `cbind` will give you a data frame back. `class(cbind(mtcars, 1))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a `list` column and `unnest`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   mutate(z = list(1:3)) %>%
   unnest %>%
   arrange(z)
#  x y z
#1 1 3 1
#2 2 4 1
#3 1 3 2
#4 2 4 2
#5 1 3 3
#6 2 4 3
```

Comment: Another 'verse idiom for z being a df-counter: `dplyr::bind_rows(rep(list(df), 3), .id="z")`

Comment: @Frank  Thanks, my first thought was along the `bind_rows` way

Answer (score 5):

You can also do it with a `merge`:

```
dfz <- data.frame(z = 1:3)

merge(df, dfz)

#   x y z
# 1 1 3 1
# 2 2 4 1
# 3 1 3 2
# 4 2 4 2
# 5 1 3 3
# 6 2 4 3
```

Answer (score 3):

We can also do a cross join with `sqldf`. This creates a Cartesian Product of `df` and the `reps` tables:

```
library(sqldf)
reps <- data.frame(z = 1:3)

sqldf("select * from df, reps order by z")
```

or simply with `map_dfr` from `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)

map_dfr(1:3, ~cbind(df, z = .))
```

**Output:**

```
  x y z
1 1 3 1
2 2 4 1
3 1 3 2
4 2 4 2
5 1 3 3
6 2 4 3
```

Comment: haha that would have been another option for sql dinosaurs like me

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option using `base R`

```
n <- 3
do.call(rbind, 
        Map(`[<-`, replicate(n = n, 
                             expr = df, 
                             simplify = FALSE), 
            "z", 
            value = seq_len(n)))
#  x y z
#1 1 3 1
#2 2 4 1
#3 1 3 2
#4 2 4 2
#5 1 3 3
#6 2 4 3
```

Answer (score 1):

A few other ways not covered yet:

```
# setup
df = data.frame(x = c(1, 2), y = c(3, 4))
n = 3

# simple row indexing, add column manually
result = df[rep(1:nrow(df), 3), ]
result$id = rep(1:n, each = nrow(df))

# cross join in base
merge(df, data.frame(id = 1:n), by = NULL)

# cross join in tidyr
tidyr::crossing(df, data.frame(id = 1:n))

# dplyr version of the row-index method above
slice(df, rep(1:n(), n)) %>% mutate(id = rep(1:n, each = nrow(df)))
```

Inspiration drawn heavily from an old question of mine, [How can I repeat a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13275260/903061). Basically the same question but without the `id` column requirement.