# extract data from loop use R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

when i use command print  in my loop i have 6140 raws:

```
for (i in 1:614 ){
print(paste(urls[i], 0:10)))
}
```

but i don't know how extract all values to data frame
When I tru create variable :

```
for (i in 1:614 ){
 a<- as.data.frame(paste(urls[i], 1:10))
  }
```

i have only 10 obj wit my links.

In general, i want have  6140 obj with my data

P.S.sorry for my english :)

Comment: what is `urls`? A character vector? A data frame? A list? If it's a data frame, have a look at [this existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121385/repeat-rows-of-a-data-frame).

Comment: urls is character vector

Comment: `data.frame(rep(urls, each=10))` will give you a data frame with each element of the `urls` vector repeated 10 times. If you plan to do any real work in R, you'll benefit from taking a look at how to do vectorized operations. The [R tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) here on SO is a good place to start for resources to learn R better.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the easiest way to do what you want is to use the [`foreach` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf). It provides a `.combine` argument that makes joining together the results from each cycle super easy.

```
# Create a reproducible example of urls
urls <- rep_len (letters, 614)

# Install and load `foreach`
install.packages ("foreach")
library (foreach)

# Create the loop and indicate that you want to join the results by row
a <- foreach (i=1:614, .combine = rbind) %do% {
  as.data.frame (paste(urls[i], 0:10))
}
```

That's it. You can combine the results in many kinds of classes (vectors, data frames, lists, etc) and ways (by row, by column, etc). Learning to use `foreach` won't only be beneficial for this problem, but it will be also very useful, if later you need to do some kind of parallel computation.

If you want to stick to a traditional loop, one of the many ways to do it is:

```
a <- data.frame ()
for (i in 1:614){
  a <- rbind (a, as.data.frame (paste(urls[i], 0:10)))
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Nice solution. (+1). But, the vectorized solution `data.frame(paste(rep(urls, each=11), 0:10))` given by @hrbrmstr is much better in this case, IMHO.