# Python - Replicating Rows By unique Indicator within Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From:

```
    ID | Count | IC     | Supplier |  
    123 | 43   | 124234 | /A/B/C   |
```

To:

```
ID  | Count | IC     | Supplier |  
123 | 43    | 124234 | /A       |  
123 | 43    | 124234 | /B       |      
123 | 43    | 124234 | /C       |
```

Hi Guys , as explained in the 1st table in image , I would like to convert it to the second table. In essence:

1. To replicate rows based on content of Column ' Supplier'
2. Every row contains a unique value of Supplier

Refer to image for more info.

Thanks in advance , this is very similar to [R - Replicating Rows By Indicator within Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37127282/r-replicating-rows-by-indicator-within-column), but i am looking for the python solution.

Cheers
Tonz

Comment: Please post code and data as text, not images.

Comment: Hi i was told by stackflow i don't have the authority to post images here yet. When i do so , it was converted into an image

Comment: My comment was that you shouldn't be posting images of data. You should cut and paste the *actual* data into the question. It makes it a lot easier for people to answer as they can work with the data you are using.

Comment: I have coded it into a table like form. The dataset was in excel , when i cut and paste , it generates a link leading to the image