# Creating duplicate in R

Tags: r

I have the following input data frame with 4 columns and 3 rows.
The time column can take value from 1 to the corresponding value of the maturity column for that customer, I want to create more observations for each customer till the value of time is = value of maturity, with the other columns retaining their original value. Please see the below links for input and expected output

Input

[image: Input]

Output

[image: Output]

Comment: Images are not a good way of posting data (or code). [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the code you've tried and with the output of `dput(df)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` solution inspired but not exactly equal to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38237805/8245406).

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(custno = 1:3, time = 1, dept = c("A", "B", "A"))

df %>% 
  slice(rep(1:n(), each = 5)) %>%
  group_by(custno) %>%
  mutate(time = seq_along(time))
```

## Edit

After the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63816444/creating-duplicate-in-r/63816693?noredirect=1#comment112848688_63816693) by the OP, the following seems to be better.

First, the data:

```
df <- data.frame(custno = 1:3, time = 1, 
                 dept = c("A", "B", "A"),
                 maturity = c(5,4,6))
```

And the solution.

```
df %>% 
  tidyr::uncount(maturity) %>%
  group_by(custno) %>%
  mutate(time = seq_along(time))
```

Comment: df <- data.frame(custno = 1:3, time = 1, dept = c("A", "B", "A"),maturity = c(5,4,6))  

 df <- df %>% 
     slice(rep(1:n(), each = df$maturity)) %>%
     group_by(custno) %>%
     mutate(time = seq_along(time))

Comment: i tried the above, basically, time should iterate till the value in maturity for each row

Comment: time should iterate till the value in maturity for each row.

Comment: Worked like a Gem !! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `slice` with `row_number`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
    slice(rep(row_number(), maturity)) %>%
    mutate(time = rowid(custno))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(custno = 1:3, time = 1, 
                 dept = c("A", "B", "A"),
                 maturity = c(5,4,6))
```