# Attaching a same dataframe for each row in the original dataframe

Tags: r, join, merge, cbind

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
     First  Last
1  Aamira Chaudhry
2  Abby   Adams
3  Ada    Sarmento




structure(list(First = c("Aamira", "Abby", "Ada"), `Last ` = c("Chaudhry", 
    "Adams", "Sarmento")), .Names = c("First", "Last "), row.names = c(NA, 
    -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Is the code.

I also have a dataframe

```
middle <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

I want to attach the a, b, and c for each row in the original dataframe. 
I want to end up with something like this:

```
    First Last    Middle
1  Aamira Chaudhry  a
2  Aamira Chaudhry  b
3  Aamira Chaudhry  c
4  Abby   Adams     a
5  Abby   Adams     b
6  Abby   Adams     c
7  Ada    Sarmento  a
8  Ada    Sarmento  b
9  Ada    Sarmento  c
```

I tried looking up stackoverflow but didn't really work out. How should I do this?

Thanks

Comment: `dat = as.data.frame(dat) ; cbind(dat[rep(rownames(dat), each=length(middle)), ], middle)`

Comment: wow. works like magic! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repeat rows of a data.frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121385/repeat-rows-of-a-data-frame) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894775/replicate-each-row-of-data-frame-and-specify-the-number-of-replications-for-each

Comment: `tidyr::crossing(df, middle)`

Comment: or `library(tidyverse); df %>% mutate(Middle = list(middle)) %>% unnest()`

Comment: Just `merge(middle, df)` will do it.