# Loop a data frame so that a unique variable is repeated 7 times corresponding to the day of the week in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a data frame with 8 columns and 177 rows. I need to loop this data frame over each day of the week so that each unique ID is repeated 7 times corresponding to the day of the week: Monday, Tuesday, etc.

I have tried searching for an answer to this, but have been unable to find one.

```
               [The image provides the first six rows of my current output. Columns v1, v2, and v3 all have unique values (v1 and v2 change in later rows) ][1]
```

I need it so that each row repeats seven times and corresponds to the day of the week.

Comment: Could you explain more? Maybe using a little example to illustrate the data frame you already have and the effect you want to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replicate each row of data.frame and specify the number of replications for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894775/replicate-each-row-of-data-frame-and-specify-the-number-of-replications-for-each)

Comment: Thanks! Found a little more helpful function here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121385/repeat-rows-of-a-data-frame. Solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use the `CJ()` function (*cross join*) from `data.table`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:177, x1 = 1234L)

library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[CJ(id = id, weekday = 1:7), on = "id"]
```

> ```
>        id   x1 weekday
>    1:   1 1234       1
>    2:   1 1234       2
>    3:   1 1234       3
>    4:   1 1234       4
>    5:   1 1234       5
>   ---                 
> 1235: 177 1234       3
> 1236: 177 1234       4
> 1237: 177 1234       5
> 1238: 177 1234       6
> 1239: 177 1234       7
> ```