# Generate data.frame from frequency table

Tags: r

I have synthetic data in a 2*4 array with 500 observations:

```
datax = array(c(120, 181, 50, 43, 41, 33,24,8), dim=c(2,4))
dimnames(datax) = list(gender= c('male', 'female')
                    , punishment = c('None', 'Community_service', 'Youth_prison', 'Normal_prison'))
```

I'd like to produce a `data.frame` from the table that represents the "source" of the frequency table.

I can represent it through a "Freq" column (`as.data.frame(as.table(datax))`, also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758961/how-to-convert-a-table-to-a-data-frame)) but I'd like to produce the data.frame with 500 rows and 2 columns (gender, punishment).

How would I do this in R?

Comment: This is probably a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121385/repeat-rows-of-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
long <- as.data.frame.table(datax)
longer <- long[rep(1:nrow(long), long$Freq), -3]
```

Comment: That's exactly it. Fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr:

```
as.data.frame.table(datax) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    do(data.frame(rep(.$gender, .$Freq), .$punishment))
```

This constructs a new table for every row in your data, repeating `Freq` times, and concatenates them into one giant table.