# From frequency table to obervations

Tags: r

I am trying to **efficiently** build a data frame that could represent the source of a frequency table in R.

Easy example:

```
A <- data.frame(Age=c(20,60,20,60), Health=c("Good","Good","Bad","Bad"), Frequency=c(53,13,23,31))
```

What I would like to have is a matrix that would have generated the above distribution. 
Is there a quick way to do it?

Comment: Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54787908/generate-data-frame-from-frequency-table

Answer (score 0):

How about this apply approach?

```
B <- apply(A,1,function(x){matrix(c(x[1],x[2]),ncol = 2, nrow = as.numeric(x[3]), byrow = TRUE)})
B <- do.call(rbind,B)
colnames(B) <- c("Age","Health")
```

Comment: That would work, but what if we have 10 different variables in the contingency table? I am looking for a quick way to do it regardless of the number of dimensions... ideally using a single function

Comment: Yeah, in that case, use `data.frame.table` as recommended by @Ben.