# How can I split rows up by the number of times located in a column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, split

For example, suppose you have the following dataframe:

```
ID<-c("11", "12", "13", "14", "14")
Date<-c("2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-15", "2020-04-10", "2020-06-01")
Item<-c("Item1", "Item1", "Item2", "Item2", "Item2")
ItemPrice<-c(5, 5, 7, 7, 7)
Quantity<-c(1, 2, -2, 2, 3)
Cost<-c(5, 10, -14, 14, 21)
df<-data.frame(ID, Date, Item, ItemPrice, Quantity, Cost)
df

  ID       Date  Item ItemPrice Quantity Cost
1 11 2020-01-01 Item1         5        1    5
2 12 2020-02-01 Item1         5        2   10
3 13 2020-03-15 Item2         7       -2  -14
4 14 2020-04-10 Item2         7        2   14
5 14 2020-06-01 Item2         7        3   21
```

However, you wanted to separate the rows by `Quantity` so each one represents an individual sale like the following:

```
   ID       Date  Item ItemPrice Quantity Cost
1  11 2020-01-01 Item1         5        1    5
2  12 2020-02-01 Item1         5        1    5
3  12 2020-02-01 Item1         5        1    5
4  13 2020-03-15 Item2         7       -1   -7
5  13 2020-03-15 Item2         7       -1   -7
6  14 2020-04-10 Item2         7        1    7
7  14 2020-04-10 Item2         7        1    7
8  14 2020-06-01 Item2         7        1    7
9  14 2020-06-01 Item2         7        1    7
10 14 2020-06-01 Item2         7        1    7
```

How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a base R way. I was going to close as duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121385/repeat-rows-of-a-data-frame) but there are small differences. The main instruction, the `lapply` loop is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52305196/8245406).

```
df$Cost <- df$Cost/abs(df$Quantity)
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, rep, abs(df$Quantity)))
df$Quantity <- sign(df$Quantity)

df
#   ID       Date  Item ItemPrice Quantity Cost
#1  11 2020-01-01 Item1         5        1    5
#2  12 2020-02-01 Item1         5        1    5
#3  12 2020-02-01 Item1         5        1    5
#4  13 2020-03-15 Item2         7       -1   -7
#5  13 2020-03-15 Item2         7       -1   -7
#6  14 2020-04-10 Item2         7        1    7
#7  14 2020-04-10 Item2         7        1    7
#8  14 2020-06-01 Item2         7        1    7
#9  14 2020-06-01 Item2         7        1    7
#10 14 2020-06-01 Item2         7        1    7
```

Answer (score 7):

Create a count column with the `abs`olute value of 'Quantity', change the 'Quantity' to `sign` of it, replace the 'Cost' by dividing it with 'cnt' column, and then replicate the rows with 'cnt' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(cnt = abs(Quantity), Quantity = sign(Quantity), 
         Cost = Cost/cnt) %>%
   uncount(cnt) %>%
   as_tibble
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 6
#   ID    Date       Item  ItemPrice Quantity  Cost
#   <chr> <chr>      <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 11    2020-01-01 Item1         5        1     5
# 2 12    2020-02-01 Item1         5        1     5
# 3 12    2020-02-01 Item1         5        1     5
# 4 13    2020-03-15 Item2         7       -1    -7
# 5 13    2020-03-15 Item2         7       -1    -7
# 6 14    2020-04-10 Item2         7        1     7
# 7 14    2020-04-10 Item2         7        1     7
# 8 14    2020-06-01 Item2         7        1     7
# 9 14    2020-06-01 Item2         7        1     7
#10 14    2020-06-01 Item2         7        1     7
```

Answer (score 5):

A `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) rep(x / abs(Quantity), abs(Quantity))), ID:ItemPrice]     
    ID       Date  Item ItemPrice Quantity Cost
 1: 11 2020-01-01 Item1         5        1    5
 2: 12 2020-02-01 Item1         5        1    5
 3: 12 2020-02-01 Item1         5        1    5
 4: 13 2020-03-15 Item2         7       -1   -7
 5: 13 2020-03-15 Item2         7       -1   -7
 6: 14 2020-04-10 Item2         7        1    7
 7: 14 2020-04-10 Item2         7        1    7
 8: 14 2020-06-01 Item2         7        1    7
 9: 14 2020-06-01 Item2         7        1    7
10: 14 2020-06-01 Item2         7        1    7
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this may sound a bit adventurous, But I like to constantly challenge myself to alternative solutions. Thought you might be interested:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Quantity = map(Quantity, ~ rep(.x/abs(.x), abs(.x)))) %>%
  unnest_longer(Quantity) %>%
  add_count(ID, Date) %>%
  mutate(Cost = Cost / n) %>%
  select(-n)

# A tibble: 10 x 6
   ID    Date       Item  ItemPrice Quantity  Cost
   <chr> <chr>      <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 11    2020-01-01 Item1         5        1     5
 2 12    2020-02-01 Item1         5        1     5
 3 12    2020-02-01 Item1         5        1     5
 4 13    2020-03-15 Item2         7       -1    -7
 5 13    2020-03-15 Item2         7       -1    -7
 6 14    2020-04-10 Item2         7        1     7
 7 14    2020-04-10 Item2         7        1     7
 8 14    2020-06-01 Item2         7        1     7
 9 14    2020-06-01 Item2         7        1     7
10 14    2020-06-01 Item2         7        1     7
```

Comment: Good solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr` only. You can use `rowwise()` and `slice` with a helper `ntimes`column

```
 library(dplyr)

 df %>% 
    mutate(ntimes = abs(Quantity)) %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    slice(rep(1:n(), each=abs(Quantity))) %>% 
    mutate(Cost = Cost/ntimes,
           Quantity = Quantity/ntimes) %>% 
    select(-ntimes)
```

Output:

```
   ID    Date       Item  ItemPrice Quantity  Cost
   <chr> <chr>      <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 11    2020-01-01 Item1         5        1     5
 2 12    2020-02-01 Item1         5        1     5
 3 12    2020-02-01 Item1         5        1     5
 4 13    2020-03-15 Item2         7       -1    -7
 5 13    2020-03-15 Item2         7       -1    -7
 6 14    2020-04-10 Item2         7        1     7
 7 14    2020-04-10 Item2         7        1     7
 8 14    2020-06-01 Item2         7        1     7
 9 14    2020-06-01 Item2         7        1     7
10 14    2020-06-01 Item2         7        1     7
```

Comment: For a moment I thought our ideas corresponded again :)))