# Data.Table Full Outer Join in R without key

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have a data set as follows:
dt1 =

| customerid | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1356 | 0.26 |
| 1298 | 0.38 |

dt2 =

| project_yr | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.31 |
| 2 | 0.79 |

I want to merge/ join them to get the following output:

| customerid | value | project_yr | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1356 | 0.26 | 1 | 0.31 |
| 1356 | 0.26 | 2 | 0.79 |
| 1298 | 0.38 | 1 | 0.31 |
| 1298 | 0.38 | 2 | 0.79 |

Is the quickest way to replicate df1 (similar to this [Repeat rows of a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121385/repeat-rows-of-a-data-frame)) and then merge the second one on?

Or is there a way to do it using the data.table merge function?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a cross join

```
setkey(dt1[,c(k=1,.SD)],k) [ dt2[,c(k=1,.SD)], allow.cartesian=TRUE ][,k:=NULL]
```

Comment: Isn't there any easier way for cross join already?

Comment: `dt1[, as.list(dt2), names(dt1)]`
Happy to learn other methods :)

Comment: Probably it wasn't yet merged to master branch and waits in open PRs then

Comment: Oh is there a cleaner x join syntax coming? Exciting. @jangorecki could we have the link to that GitHub page please?

Comment: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4370 and there is also #4544 which plugs it into [ operator.

Answer (score 0):

```r
dt1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~customerid, ~value,
  1356L,   0.26,
  1298L,   0.38
)

dt2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~project_yr, ~value,
  1L,   0.31,
  2L,   0.79
)

tidyr::expand_grid(dt1, dt2, .name_repair = "minimal")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   customerid value project_yr value
#>        <int> <dbl>      <int> <dbl>
#> 1       1356  0.26          1  0.31
#> 2       1356  0.26          2  0.79
#> 3       1298  0.38          1  0.31
#> 4       1298  0.38          2  0.79
```

Comment: Thankyou! Is there a way to do this using data.table package tho?

Comment: Yes: function `data.table::CJ`