# Equivalent of do.call(rbind, list) but by using pipe operator + dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to use the dplyr package (like the pipe operator: `%>%`) when i bind rows from several lists.

Now the issue is that I need the list names also to be added to the column. With `do.call(rbind, list)` this happens automatically, what is the dplyr equivalent?

I've tried `list.object %>% rbind_all()` and `list.object %>% bind_rows` which gives the same effect with no list names following.

Comment: Using `data.table` , `rbindlist(yourlist, idcol=TRUE)`

Comment: In the current version of **dplyr** `bind_rows` has a `.id` argument, along the same lines as outlined above for **data.table**.

Comment: thank you @joran just what I was looking for!

Comment: I found the last suggestion in the accepted answer here very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753531/repeat-rows-of-a-data-frame-n-times