# Repeat data frame with varying date column

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I repeat a data frame with varying date column at the end? If I apply one of the [previously recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753531/repeat-data-frame-n-times) ways, all the columns get repeated. For example:

```
df<-data.frame(x1=c(1:3), x2=c('z','g','h'), x3=c( rep( as.Date("2011-07-31"), by=1, len=3)) )
n=2
do.call("rbind", replicate(n, df, simplify = FALSE))

   x1 x2        x3
1  1  z 2011-07-31
2  2  g 2011-07-31
3  3  h 2011-07-31
4  1  z 2011-07-31
5  2  g 2011-07-31
6  3  h 2011-07-31
```

Whereas what I need is:

```
  x1 x2         x3
1  1  z 2011-07-31
2  2  g 2011-07-31
3  3  h 2011-07-31
4  1  z 2011-08-01
5  2  g 2011-08-01
6  3  h 2011-08-01
```

Comment: In your dataset, it is `-07-31` how come it changed to `07-01`

Comment: @akrun No. My code replicates the date as its "2011-07-31". Whereas what I need is it to change in each iteration. The other issue is my typo sorry. Will fix it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another base R method that works for your example.

```
# save result
dat <- do.call("rbind", replicate(n, df, simplify = FALSE))

# update x3 variable
dat$x3 <- dat$x3 + cumsum(dat$x1 == 1) - 1
```

The logic is that we use a cumulative sum that is incremented every time x1 returns to its initial value (here 1). We subtract 1 from the result as we don't want to alter the first block.

this returns

```
dat
  x1 x2         x3
1  1  z 2011-07-31
2  2  g 2011-07-31
3  3  h 2011-07-31
4  1  z 2011-08-01
5  2  g 2011-08-01
6  3  h 2011-08-01
```

Using `transform`, this can be written

```
transform(dat, x3 = x3 + cumsum(x1 == 1) - 1)
```

---

As an alternative counting procedure, we could use `seq_len` together with `rep` like this

```
# update x3 variable
dat$x3 <- dat$x3 + rep(seq_len(n)-1L, each=nrow(df))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
> n=2
> df1 <- df[rep(1:nrow(df), n),]
> transform(df1, x3=ave(x3, x1, FUN=function(x) x + 1:length(x) - 1L))
    x1 x2         x3
1    1  z 2011-07-31
2    2  g 2011-07-31
3    3  h 2011-07-31
1.1  1  z 2011-08-01
2.1  2  g 2011-08-01
3.1  3  h 2011-08-01
```

or

```
> library(dplyr)
> df1 <- df[rep(1:nrow(df), n),]
> df1 %>% group_by(x1,x2) %>% mutate(x3= x3 + 1:n() - 1L)
```