# R - Replicate data table and create sequential dates

Tags: r, date, data.table

I have the following data table:

```
dt <- data.table(date=c(seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-01"),as.Date("2000-01-03"),"1 day")),
                 a=c(1,2,3),
                 b=c(1,2,3),
                 c=c(1,2,3))
> dt
         date a b c
1: 2000-01-01 1 1 1
2: 2000-01-02 2 2 2
3: 2000-01-03 3 3 3
```

and I need to replicate it `n` times (code taken from [Repeat data.frame N times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753531/repeat-data-frame-n-times/8753732)):

```
n <- 3
dt.rep <- dt[rep(seq_len(nrow(dt)), n)]

> dt.rep
         date a b c
1: 2000-01-01 1 1 1
2: 2000-01-02 2 2 2
3: 2000-01-03 3 3 3
4: 2000-01-01 1 1 1
5: 2000-01-02 2 2 2
6: 2000-01-03 3 3 3
7: 2000-01-01 1 1 1
8: 2000-01-02 2 2 2
9: 2000-01-03 3 3 3
```

However, I need the `date` column to be sequential. The last row would be the actual last date, and I need it to go backwards to the first row, so the expected output is:

```
         date a b c
1: 1999-12-26 1 1 1
2: 1999-12-27 2 2 2
3: 1999-12-28 3 3 3
4: 1999-12-29 1 1 1
5: 1999-12-30 2 2 2
6: 1999-12-31 3 3 3
7: 2000-01-01 1 1 1
8: 2000-01-02 2 2 2
9: 2000-01-03 3 3 3
```

How to achieve this?

EDIT:

The proposed solution seems to fail for large, hourly datasets. Consider this new example:

```
dt <- data.table(date=seq(as.POSIXct("1994-01-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2008-12-31 23:00:00"), by="1 hour"), temp=runif(n=131496, min=10, max=35)) 
> dt
                       date     temp
     1: 1994-01-01 00:00:00 26.40286
     2: 1994-01-01 01:00:00 21.37171
     3: 1994-01-01 02:00:00 16.11227
     4: 1994-01-01 03:00:00 30.28062
     5: 1994-01-01 04:00:00 25.22336
    ---                             
131492: 2008-12-31 19:00:00 18.43148
131493: 2008-12-31 20:00:00 24.10905
131494: 2008-12-31 21:00:00 10.33235
131495: 2008-12-31 22:00:00 27.73049
131496: 2008-12-31 23:00:00 21.74835
```

When replicating it `5` times, this is what we have:

```
n <- 5
dt[rep(seq_len(.N), n)][, newdate:=rev(seq(last(date),
                                           length.out=.N, by='-1 hour'))][]
                       date     temp             newdate
     1: 1994-01-01 00:00:00 26.40286 1933-12-31 00:00:00
     2: 1994-01-01 01:00:00 21.37171 1933-12-31 01:00:00
     3: 1994-01-01 02:00:00 16.11227 1933-12-31 02:00:00
     4: 1994-01-01 03:00:00 30.28062 1933-12-31 03:00:00
     5: 1994-01-01 04:00:00 25.22336 1933-12-31 04:00:00
    ---                                                 
657476: 2008-12-31 19:00:00 18.43148 2008-12-31 19:00:00
657477: 2008-12-31 20:00:00 24.10905 2008-12-31 20:00:00
657478: 2008-12-31 21:00:00 10.33235 2008-12-31 21:00:00
657479: 2008-12-31 22:00:00 27.73049 2008-12-31 22:00:00
657480: 2008-12-31 23:00:00 21.74835 2008-12-31 23:00:00
```

Notice how the `date` and `newdate` columns are out of sync.
I would expect `newdate` to start on `1934-01-01 00:00:00`, but rather it starts on `1933-12-31 00:00:00`. This results in the data table having 76 (`length(unique(year(dt$newdate)))`) years of data, rather than `5` replications of the `15 years` in the original one = `75` years. I am not sure what is going on here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `rep`lication step, using the `last` 'date', get the `rev`erse `seq`uence of 'date' by specifying the `length.out` as `.N` (number of rows and `by` as negative 1 day

```
dt[rep(seq_len(.N), n)][, date := rev(seq(last(date),
       length.out = .N, by = '-1 day'))][]
#         date a b c
#1: 1999-12-26 1 1 1
#2: 1999-12-27 2 2 2
#3: 1999-12-28 3 3 3
#4: 1999-12-29 1 1 1
#5: 1999-12-30 2 2 2
#6: 1999-12-31 3 3 3
#7: 2000-01-01 1 1 1
#8: 2000-01-02 2 2 2
#9: 2000-01-03 3 3 3
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's comments, it seems that the 'date' sequence should be `rev`ersed for each replication.  In that case, we can use the `rep`lication as a grouping variable

```
n <- 5
dt[rep(seq_len(.N), n)][, newdate := rev(seq(last(date),
   length.out = .N, by='-1 hour')), by = .(rep(seq_len(n), each = nrow(dt)))][]
#                  date     temp             newdate
#1: 1994-01-01 00:00:00 34.19615 1994-01-01 00:00:00
#2: 1994-01-01 01:00:00 34.29310 1994-01-01 01:00:00
# ...
```

NOTE: Using the updated data in OP's post

Comment: I noticed that the code doesn't work properly with larger datasets. Please try your answer with this data table: `dt <- data.table(date=seq(as.POSIXct("1994-01-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2008-12-31 23:00:00"), by="1 hour"),
                 temp=runif(n=131496, min=10, max=35))
`, replacing `-1 day` with `-1 hour` in your answer.

Comment: @thiagoveloso  Can you tell me the issue you noticed with the hourly sequence

Comment: Please take a look at the edit I made in the original post.

Comment: @thiagoveloso I tested it with first with the same data and it works fine `dt[, newdate := rev(seq(last(date), length.out=.N, by='-1 hour'))]#
 head(dt)#
                  date     temp             newdate
1: 1994-01-01 00:00:00 17.05952 1994-01-01 00:00:00``  Now, we look at how things are working with each replication.  For e.g. `n1 <- 131496` i.e. the number of rows of original data.  `> tail(seq(last(dt$date), length.out = n1 * 3, by = '-1 hour'), 1)
[1] "1964-01-01 EST"
> tail(seq(last(dt$date), length.out = n1 * 4, by = '-1 hour'), 1)
[1] "1948-12-31 EST"`

Comment: For replication '5', it is `> tail(seq(last(dt$date), length.out = n1 * 5, by = '-1 hour'), 1)
[1] "1933-12-31 EST"``  It means, we are taking the sequence from the last element to the first element i.e 131496 * 5

Comment: @thiagoveloso  If you really wanted to reflect the changes for each replication, then do a group by sequence i.e. `dt[rep(seq_len(.N), n)][, newdate := rev(seq(last(date),length.out=.N, by='-1 hour')), .(rep(seq_len(n), each = nrow(dt)))][]#
                       date     temp             newdate
     1: 1994-01-01 00:00:00 34.19615 1994-01-01 00:00:00
     2: 1994-01-01 01:00:00 34.29310 1994-01-01 01:00:00`

Comment: The issue is that, like you demonstrated, the last element in each replication falls on different days (e.g. Jan 1 vs Dec 31). Shouldn't they fall on the same day, but different years?

Comment: @thiagoveloso  Not sure about the logic you want to accomplish