# copy data from one row to a new row in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table, copy, row

I have a table like follows:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(t0.id=1:2,t0.V1=c("a","e"),t0.V2=c("b","f"),t1.id=3:4,t1.V1=c("c","g"),t1.V2=c("d","h"))

dt
   t0.id t0.V1 t0.V2 t1.id t1.V1 t1.V2
1:     1     a     b     3     c     d
2:     2     e     f     4     g     h
```

and I want to copy data from row one to a new row, like this:

```
   t0.id t0.V1 t0.V2 t1.id t1.V1 t1.V2
1:     1     a     b                  
2:                       3     c     d
3:     2     e     f     4     g     h
```

I know how to duplicate the row (I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57918661/r-data-table-how-to-create-duplicates)), but I don't know how to clear columns by condition (eg. t0.id==1) since both rows would be equal.

I guess it could be done by row index, but my real table has thousands of rows and I don't think that's the best way to do it.

Thank you

EDIT:

- The final order of rows doesn't matter, that is, final rows no 1 and 2 don't need to be next to each other.
- I 'manually' (by looking at some variables) identify which rows need to be split. So, the only condition to be applied is based on 't0.id'.

Comment: Please explain what conditional you're using to determine that `t0.id == 1` needs to be split. Also, does the resulting order of rows matter?

Comment: I just edit my post to answer your questions, @r2evans. Hope it helps. If you need more details please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(data.table)
splitids <- 1L # t0.id
out <- rbindlist(list(
    dt[t0.id %in% splitids, .SD, .SDcols = patterns("^t0")],
    dt[t0.id %in% splitids, .SD, .SDcols = patterns("^t1")],
    dt[!t0.id %in% splitids,]),
  use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
out
#    t0.id  t0.V1  t0.V2 t1.id  t1.V1  t1.V2
#    <int> <char> <char> <int> <char> <char>
# 1:     1      a      b    NA   <NA>   <NA>
# 2:    NA   <NA>   <NA>     3      c      d
# 3:     2      e      f     4      g      h
```

It may make more sense if you look at each of them:

```r
dt[t0.id %in% splitids, .SD, .SDcols = patterns("^t0")]
#    t0.id  t0.V1  t0.V2
#    <int> <char> <char>
# 1:     1      a      b
dt[t0.id %in% splitids, .SD, .SDcols = patterns("^t1")]
#    t1.id  t1.V1  t1.V2
#    <int> <char> <char>
# 1:     3      c      d
dt[!t0.id %in% splitids,]
#    t0.id  t0.V1  t0.V2 t1.id  t1.V1  t1.V2
#    <int> <char> <char> <int> <char> <char>
# 1:     2      e      f     4      g      h
```

If you need the blank `""` instead of `NA`, then that can be done to your `character` columns, but not to the `t*.id` columns since that would convert them from `integer` to `character`.

```r
ischr <- which(sapply(dt, inherits, "character"))
ischr
# t0.V1 t0.V2 t1.V1 t1.V2 
#     2     3     5     6 
out[, (ischr) := lapply(.SD, fcoalesce, ""), .SDcols = ischr][]
#    t0.id  t0.V1  t0.V2 t1.id  t1.V1  t1.V2
#    <int> <char> <char> <int> <char> <char>
# 1:     1      a      b    NA              
# 2:    NA                   3      c      d
# 3:     2      e      f     4      g      h
```