# Boolean comparison between dataframe and vector wrong

Tags: r

I simplified the issue to the following situation:

There is a dataframe `df` (which is a subsection of another where the previous four rows are just NaN):

```
  R_shunt R_Bosch    R_1    R_2    R_3   R_4   R_5   R_6    R_7   R_8
5   81317  138404 102678 135544 158359 83282 86151 90371 119277 98487
6  128501  118684 101001 102568 169562 78182 72561 85573  70014 95572
```

and there is another dataframe or vector or list (so far the type doesn't matter, apparently):

`comp`:

```
[1]  52398 115826  82691 139825 126657 125659  96578  94017  81740 126819
```

Now I want to know which cells of `df` are less than the cells of `comp`:

```
df > comp
  R_shunt R_Bosch   R_1  R_2  R_3   R_4   R_5   R_6   R_7   R_8
5    TRUE    TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
6    TRUE   FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

which is somehow wrong. This here is a column-wise comparison, e.g. only the first column of `df` shall be compared with the first column of `comp`. For example, `R_Bosch` in the sixth row should be `TRUE`. I don't get it.

When I set up `comp` like this:

```
comp = c(100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000)
```

and compare, it is correct:

```
> df> comp
  R_shunt R_Bosch  R_1  R_2  R_3   R_4   R_5   R_6   R_7   R_8
5   FALSE    TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
6    TRUE    TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Now, when I do it manually but use the aimed values like

```
comp = c(52398, 115826, 82691, 139825, 126657, 125659, 96578, 94017, 81740, 126819)

> df> comp
  R_shunt R_Bosch   R_1  R_2  R_3   R_4   R_5   R_6   R_7   R_8
5    TRUE    TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
6    TRUE   FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

it is still wrong.

I must systemically misunderstand something.

Comment: You're comparing 20 values in a data frame to 10 values in a vector. It's not clear to me how you want to match those 20 values to those 10 values - clearly the top left value the data frame gets compare to `comp[1]`, but what gets compared to `comp[2]`, `df[1, 2]` or `df[2, 1]`? - R makes one assumption, you make the other.

Comment: which assumption does R make? In both data frames there are 10 columns, so I thought it would be compared column-wise? To be more concise: In my assumption comp[2] should be compared to df[1, 2] and df[2,2]

Comment: It is what I would call "columnwise" - it goes down the items in each column of `df`, `df[1, 1] > comp[1]`, then still in the first column `df[2, 1] > comp[2]`, etc. You seem to want what I would call "rowwise" - first row of `df` compared to `comp`, then second row of `df` compared to `comp`. But don't say "both data frames" - `comp` is just a vector. If you turn `comp` into a data frame you'll get a nice error message telling you that data frames of different shapes can't be compared: try `df > as.data.frame(t(comp))`

Comment: True, "row-wise" makes more sense. So this feature seems to not exist? Or is there any workaround or a package you know, maybe? Otherwise I will do it "column-wise" then :)
Yes, the dataframe didn't work. Maybe  I extend the vector to a dataframe, then it should work..

Comment: Where do you want the results?  Do you want to replace the existing numbers of make new columns or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few options:

```
## make comp the same shape as the data
## (fine with this example, impractical if you have more rows)
df > rbind(comp, comp)
#   R_shunt R_Bosch  R_1   R_2  R_3   R_4   R_5   R_6   R_7   R_8
# 5    TRUE    TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# 6    TRUE    TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

## transpose df so the order works, then transpose it back
## (note this results in a matrix)
t((t(df)) > comp)
#   R_shunt R_Bosch  R_1   R_2  R_3   R_4   R_5   R_6   R_7   R_8
# 5    TRUE    TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# 6    TRUE    TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

## Use Map to iterate in parallel - first column of df vs first item of comp, ...
## (returns a list, so we convert to data frame)
as.data.frame(Map(">", df, comp))
#   R_shunt R_Bosch  R_1   R_2  R_3   R_4   R_5   R_6   R_7   R_8
# 1    TRUE    TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# 2    TRUE    TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I do that when there are more rows?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753531/repeat-rows-of-a-data-frame-n-times

Comment: Both the 2nd and 3rd methods work for any number of rows.

Answer (score 2):

When you compare a `data.frame` and a `vector`, elements in the `vector` will be recycled to match the dimension of the `data.frame`. The direction of matching is by column. Take a 2x3 `data.frame` and a `vector` of length 3 for example:

```
df

#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  a  b  c
# 2  a  b  c

vec

# [1] d e f
```

When you use the arithmetic(`+`,`-`,`*`,`/`) or logical(`>`,`<`,`==`) operators on them, the following rule will be taken:

```
df > vec

#       V1     V2     V3
# 1  a > d  b > f  c > e
# 2  a > e  b > d  c > f
```

instead of

```
#       V1     V2     V3
# 1  a > d  b > e  c > f
# 2  a > d  b > e  c > f
```

Comment: @Ben this is another way to visualize the columnwise vs rowwise discussion we had in the question comments.

Comment: I got that, I just wonder about the sytematic rule behind that. For me, it looks like using somewhat like a determinante or so..
Or in other words: How do you exactly know which cell is compared to which cell?