# Replace each observation in a data.frame with n copies

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame called X with 14 columns and 48 rows. Stata's command for what I want to do is -expand- https://www.stata.com/manuals13/dexpand.pdf

A simplified version of what I want to do is.

1. I have this data.framework (some random numbers):

```
      1  -1   0   4   2

      5   0  -1   2  -2

      3   2   0   1   2
```

2. and I want to expand it 40 times, like doing rbind(X, X, X, ..., X)

```r
      1  -1   0   4   2

      5   0  -1   2  -2

      3   2   0   1   2

      1  -1   0   4   2

      5   0  -1   2  -2

      3   2   0   1   2

      ...

      1  -1   0   4   2

      5   0  -1   2  -2

      3   2   0   1   2
```

Thank you!!

Comment: `df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), 40), ]`

Comment: This could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753531/repeat-rows-of-a-data-frame-n-times