# R: Repeat rows of a data.frame k times and add prefix to new row values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, replicate

I know from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753531/repeat-rows-of-a-data-frame-n-times) how to duplicate rows of a dataframe. That's fine if you  want to repeat the rows n times.

I want to do something similar but to also add a prefix within a column of newly added rows. Note: I am not basing the repetition count on the number of rows. It needs to be provided by a parameter (call it k).

So the operation should look like this assuming I want to repeat the dataframe k=3 times:

Input:

```r
data.frame(a = c("1","2","3", "4"),b = c(1,2,3, 4))
  a b
1 "1" 1
2 "2" 2
3 "3" 3
4 "4" 4
```

Output:

```r
  a b
1 "1" 1
2 "2" 2
3 "3" 3
4 "4" 4
5 "1_1" 1
6 "1_2" 2
7 "1_3" 3
8 "1_4" 4
9 "2_1" 1
10 "2_2" 2
11 "2_3" 3
12 "2_4" 4
```

What's a nice R way to do this??

Comment: Should row 9 be 2_3? I take it you don't want 3_1,3_2,3_3?

Comment: df %>% mutate(n = N) %>% uncount(n) %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(n = row_number() -1) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(a = paste0(a,"_",n) << no idea if this works as doing this on my phone. It might give you some ideas though

Comment: @pluke I updated the question.. there was confusion

Answer (score 4):

You could use `expand_grid` (assuming your data.frame is named `df1`):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

expand_grid(a = df1$a, b = df1$b) %>% 
  mutate(a = paste(a, b, sep = "_")) %>% 
  bind_rows(df1, .)
```

This returns

```r
     a b
1    1 1
2    2 2
3    3 3
4  1_1 1
5  1_2 2
6  1_3 3
7  2_1 1
8  2_2 2
9  2_3 3
10 3_1 1
11 3_2 2
12 3_3 3
```

Comment: My instructions were not clear enough.. please see updated question. @Martin Gal

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyverse` with `crossing`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
 data.frame(a = c("1","2","3"),b = c(1,2,3)) %>%
   add_row(crossing(!!! .) %>%
   unite(a, a, b, remove = FALSE))
```

-output

```
     a b
1    1 1
2    2 2
3    3 3
4  1_1 1
5  1_2 2
6  1_3 3
7  2_1 1
8  2_2 2
9  2_3 3
10 3_1 1
11 3_2 2
12 3_3 3
```

---

With the updated dataset and criteria

```
library(purrr) # v 1.0.0
library(stringr)
k <- 3
data.frame(a = c("1","2","3", "4"),b = c(1,2,3, 4)) %>%
   replicate(k, ., simplify = FALSE) %>% 
   setNames(seq_len(k) - 1) %>% 
   imap(~ .x %>%
     mutate(a = if(.y == 0) as.character(a) else str_c(.y, '_', a))) %>% 
   list_rbind
```

-output

```
     a b
1    1 1
2    2 2
3    3 3
4    4 4
5  1_1 1
6  1_2 2
7  1_3 3
8  1_4 4
9  2_1 1
10 2_2 2
11 2_3 3
12 2_4 4
```

---

Or with `slice` and `make.unique`

```
data.frame(a = c("1","2","3", "4"),b = c(1,2,3, 4)) %>% 
   slice(rep(row_number(), times = k)) %>% 
   mutate(a = str_replace(make.unique(a, sep = "_"), 
        "^(\\d+)_(\\d+)", "\\2_\\1"))
```

-output

```
     a b
1    1 1
2    2 2
3    3 3
4    4 4
5  1_1 1
6  1_2 2
7  1_3 3
8  1_4 4
9  2_1 1
10 2_2 2
11 2_3 3
12 2_4 4
```

Comment: My instructions were not clear enough.. please see updated question. @akrun

Comment: @Unionfind Maybe the update helps